# How to automatically change a certain part of the link to a set value

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I always manually have to change the part of the link in the iframe `src`.

Here is an example of an iframe :

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://example.com/embed-aaaaa-620x360.html"</IFRAME>
```

What I want is `620x360.html` to be `1000x450.html`

So, is there a way that will change the code for all my post that I have created on wordpress without me doing it manually.

Also in the future i will embed more videos and i do not want to manually edit everytime I post a new post.

Comment: A little context would be helpful. Where and when do you want to change this? Should the cange be persistant?

Comment: All my posts in wordpress that have embeded videos in them width and height depends on the src and i want the videos to be a ceratin height and width so they perfectly fit into the div

Answer (score 0):

To do a "search and replacement" over all blogposts on Wordpress run this SQL query (In PhpMyAdmin as a suggestion). The query will search for 620x360.html and replace it with 1000x450.html.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content,
'620x360.html',
'1000x450.html');
```

If you are uncomfortable with making queries directly against the database, there are a number of plugins that help you with this. For example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I usually first give a quick answer so the OP can test it, and then go in and give a further explanation. But thank you for your point of view! :)

Comment: What if it replaces any other values that I might not know of and may affect my site.

Comment: Yes, the code will replace all occurrences of "620x360.html". If this string accurs in other parts of your posts as well you probably should use a regular expression-solution.

Comment: @Emil TBH that isn't the right way to approach to answer OP question. Specially when answer involved doing major change.

Comment: Thanks for your opionion about my answer!